# Using local or remote databases to practice for PowerApps please?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I had been practicing PowerApps on my personal SharePoint Online account.
At work, I have local databases to connect to via ERPs, etc via SQL.
What can I use at home on my system to practice on since I don't have any other apps with SQL on it like the ERP at work to tap into. Sure I can use Excel or SharePoint but I'd like to practice on a more "work" related "tangible" ERP or something.
Is there a free practice external database or have you any other ideas? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure it's not permitted from your company to take a backup from The ERP database with **data** and restore it in your local instance to practice `Power Apps` with the same ERP database in your home.

So I suggest to just take a backup from the **database structure (without data)** (`if it allowed`) then deploy it easily in your local instance as the following:

- Open Management Studio, > Tasks > Generate Scripts.
- Select the entire database Objects or specific one as it allowed and you prefer a.
- Continue the wizard to save a **.sql** script file.
- Now, you can run this script file in your side.

**Check also,**

- [Connect to your on-premises data sources from PowerApps using on-premises data gateway](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/connect-to-your-on-premises-data-sources-using-on-premises-data-gateway-from-powerapps/)
- [Tutorial: Script objects in SQL Server Management Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/scripting-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Welcome, bro ♥,